# Singularities of a function, complex calculus

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I need to find all singularities and their type on $C \cup \{ \infty \}$ of function : $$f(z)={1 \over \exp(1/z)-1}.$$

So far I was only able to tell that function $$f(z)= {1 \over \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {1 \over z^nn!}}.$$ I think there are only essential singularities at 0 and $\infty$ but I am not able to rigorously prove it.

Comment: Your observation regarding $f$ is wrong. The expansion of $\exp(1/z)$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n n!}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, edited the post. So, I could say that there is an essential singularity at 0 because of Picard's theorem, right?

Comment: I think so. On the other hand, are you sure $\infty$ is an essential singularity? $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ has a simple pole in $z=0$.

Comment: Yes, you are complety correct. So if my calculations are right, there are also poles at $z={1 \over 2k \pi i}$? since there is $exp(1/z)=1$.

Comment: Yes, $z=\frac{1}{2k\pi i}$ are poles. I wouldn't use Picard's theorem to motivate the essential singularity though.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $f\left ( z \right )$ is differentiable at $z=\infty$  if the function $f\left ( \frac{1}{t} \right )$ is differentiable  at $t=0$. Try taking some limits, and see what you get.